# Could someone explain this line to me : return year+1, 1, 1 ?

Tags: python

The function below (written in python) takes year, month, day as its inputs and return the next day that follows the inout day:

```
def nextDay(year, month, day):
    if day < 30: 
        return year, month, day+1 
    else: 
        if month == 12: 
            return year+1, 1, 1 
        else: 
            return year, month+1, 1
```

My struggle is the line (return year+1, 1, 1), what does "1, 1" stands for ? could someone explain it to me please? 
Thanks in advance :)

Comment: They are just the numbers that represents the month and day. You should look into Python's returning multiple values and tuples.

Comment: The function returns a tuple of 3 element representing `year`, `month`, `day` respectively. So, if input day is 31 and month is 12 (i.e 31st December), then obviously next day will be 1st January of the next year. That is why 1, 1. It means month 1(jan), day 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The function is returning a tuple

```
return (year+1, 1, 1)
```

But the () are not necessary

The meaning of the tuple seems to be `(year, month, dayofmonth)`

Comment: Didn't know that was a possible in python !

Comment: Thank you John :)

Comment: Another example: `x = 1; y = 2; x, y = y, x`. Now the values are switched.

Answer (score 0):

it means when the month is 12 and day is 30 so the next day should be the first day of Jan next year.

Answer (score 0):

in the return year+1,1,1
 it means that if its december 31st he should set the next day to be year+1, 1 as in january, 1 as in day

Answer (score 0):

As you mentioned, it returns the next day. When month reaches 12, (which is December) the code increments the year and and returns the day and month as 1.

Answer (score -1):

first of all I wont use that function, In Python the library timedelta can deal with that.

Now, answering your question. That line can be executed just when the date is December 31 of any year, adding one day just increase the year and the 1,1 is because the next day is January the first and this is hardcoded just because this is always true.